# register php not working when used in android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create login register app without JSON, My login activity is working fine but register activity doesnt work dont know where I went wrong. I am using online my sql from 000webhost and stored php file in file manager. Kindly help me to find the issue. There is no problem in php because when i assign value in register.php values are inserted but it is not working.my code for register.php is [register php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4R8IuICSD_yMWNpeExrdFJaeTQ) and  and my main activity code is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    log = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

   }

   public void OnLogin(View view){

    String username = uname.getText().toString();
    String passwrd= pass.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, passwrd);
           }
public void GoReg(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
}
```

and my register java file is

```
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    unmae = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    surnme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    usernme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    passwrd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

public void OnReg(View view) {

    String sone = unmae.getText().toString();
    String stwo = surnme.getText().toString();
    String sthree = ag.getText().toString();
    String sfour = usernme.getText().toString();
    String sfive = passwrd.getText().toString();
    String type = "register";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, sone, stwo, sthree, sfour, sfive);
}
```

my background java file is linked here[background java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4R8IuICSD_yYzhHeFpFX0t0b3c)

Comment: what error you facing can you paste logcat

Comment: isn't it should be `$_POST` instead of `$POST`

Comment: thankyou now its working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_post`and check your registration page link is not available.